# Validation regular expression for windows domain user name

Tags: .net, regex, active-directory

I dug through lots of google matches but I can't find a correct, working regular expression to validate domain\username.
I have too little knowledge about regex and I know nothing about the rules of the domain and user name restrictions/rules.

Thanks,
Péter

Comment: Are you trying to check for that style of login (Ex. HQ\Jsmith), or are you trying to validate the domain and username values themselves?

Comment: I want to check the style of the login so the user can't enter: 'sm/asd' etc.

Answer (score 4):

You could just check for the presence of the backslash or forward-slash in the username.

```
string UsernameEntered = @"sm/asd";
var DomainStyleLogin = new Regex(@"^.*(\\|/)");
var match = DomainStyleLogin.Match(UsernameEntered);
if (!match.Success)
{
    //Does not contain a backslash
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to check the username or domain entered, you could use something like this :

```
var ValidUsernameOrDomain = new Regex(@"^[A-Za-z0-9\\\._-]{7,}$");
```

This will validate for :

- Match upper and lower case letters, numbers 0-9, underscore, hyphen, backslash, and period.
- String is not less than 7 characters (Minimum of 3 characters for username and domain, plus the domain slash)

Comment: Ok. Maybe I was missunderstood your question. Not the backslash the problem. I don't know the restrictions of the name of the domain and the name of the user. I want to check if the domain name and user name are also could be correct. For example it's can't contain question mark because it's not a valid domain\user composition.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using

```
/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\-\. ]{0,61}[a-zA-Z]\\\w[\w\.\- ]+$/
```

(based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33079236/359765))

Comment: This is missing spaces in the domain portion, so it doesn't match "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"

Comment: Thanks! I amended the regular expression to cater for spaces.