# What is the Regex for Windows Domain Username in C#?

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

What is the regular expression to accept only text, number and backslash. It should not accept space and should start with text only. For example domain\username. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Stackoverflow is _not_ a regex generation machine for your personal use. Please consider learning to author your own regular expressions. They are remarkably simple and powerful. If you still struggle, post an example of your attempts.

Comment: Hi Gusdor, This what I tried "^[a-zA-Z0-9\ ]+$" for accepting text, number and backslash... But not working...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this is a regex for domain\name with the restriction that 'domain' should start with a char and end with a char. You can easily maniplate the regex for your desire

```
/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z]\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/
```

Domain - Beginning:

```
    [a-zA-Z] Text
```

Domain - Text:

```
   1-61 times of [a-zA-Z0-9-] Text, Numbers, '-'
```

Domain - End:

```
   1 time [a-zA-Z] = Text
```

Backslash:

```
   1 time [\]
```

User - Text:

```
   2-infinity times [a-zA-Z] = Text
```

Edit: as bgh pointed out in the comment you could include more valid characters

```
/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9‌​\-\.]{0,61}[a-zA-Z]\\\w‌​[\w\.\- ]*$/
```

Comment: It seems that regex excludes some valid characters. I ended up using this:
/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]{0,61}[a-zA-Z]\\\w[\w\.\- ]*$/

Comment: This regular expression is overly restrictive; domain names can end with a numeral.

Comment: This is also missing spaces in the domain portion, so it doesn't match "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"

Answer (score 0):

The following is a regex with named groups, this can be pasted into Linqpad and run. Make note that actually a lot of characters are allowed in user names in Active Directory, actually any Unicode character save for some special characters (of which are used in LDAP searches among others).

Oh yes - English alphabet ends in Z. In Norwegian language we have three extra vowels: Æ,Ø,Å.

```
void Main()
{
    string user = "someaddomain\\someuser99"; 
    var matches = Regex.Match(user, @"^(?<domain>[a-æA-Æ0-9-]+)\\(?<username>[a-æA-Æ0-9-]+)$").Dump(); 
    string[] comps = user.Split('\\'); 
    comps.Dump(); 
    matches.Groups["domain"].Value.Dump(); 
    matches.Groups["username"].Value.Dump(); 
}
```

Linqpad is available for download at for those new programmers who has not used this development tool yet:
[enter link description here][1]

[1]: https://www.linqpad.net Linqpad website